# Enable cross domain not a member of hubConfiguration

Tags: vb.net

i have been developing a signalR chat application in vb.net where i'm using the below code:

```
Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
  Dim config = New HubConfiguration With {.EnableCrossDomain = True}
  app.MapHubs(config)
End Sub
```

it throws the error

> Enable cross domain not a member of hubConfiguration

Could anyone please suggest what could be the alternative to enable Cross Domain

Comment: You submitted a very basic question yesterday on the same subject. And both questions can be resolved by going through the SignalR Client tutorial [http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) It's in C# but you can use a service like Telerik to convert that over for you. Going through the tutorial will give you the correct understanding to help with your project.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial is explaining this very good:
(http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration 
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true
                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

By the way: In the case you post your code (all) it is easier to search.